# Assign GMail Address to another Domain

Tags: firebase, gmail, firebase-authentication, email

I have an existing GMail email address:

```
    xxx@gmail.com
```

I have a Firebase Account set up on this email address, which I use to do Firebase Authentication. It works perfectly, and when my app logs in, verification emails are sent to the users via this email address.

I also have a registered domain name with [1&1](http://www.1and1.com):

```
    www.yyy.com
```

1&1 also provides a service to create an email address using the domain name.  I have created the following email address:

```
    admin@yyy.com
```

I would like to mask my Gmail Email (`xxx@gmail.com`) with the `admin@yyy.com` email address.

1&1 allows all email sent to `admin@yyy.com` to be forwarded to `xxx@gmail.com`, which I can use.

**Question**

How do I get emails sent from `xxx@gmail.com` (e.g. firebase-authentication verification email), to appear as `admin@yyy.com`?

I did see in GMail, that you can create a business account (`settings -> customize addresses`), which may provide this functionality. However a business account is not free, and I have a limited budget already exhausted on domain names and server costs. Is there a free way to do this?

Any advise appreciated.

UPDATE

The [following tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SP-81LI-mw0) explains how to set up another email address (e.g. `admin@yyy.com` with your GMail address). It allows emails sent and received to appear as `admin@yyy.com`.

I however, need Firebase-Authentication to send its emails as `admin@yyy.com`. Is this possible?

UPDATE

[This tutorial](http://www.brandrevive.com/how-to-use-gmail-for-your-1and1-email/) explains how to set up linking accounts. It seems to work with sending and receiving emails. Just need to check if when Firebase sends an automated email, if it uses the correct email address.

UPDATE

Firebase sends the email from its own email address.

```
noreply@zzz-223560.firebaseapp.com
```

So I guess this is adequate. I am happy with the above solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Firebase console, go to the "Authentication" section and click on the "Templates" tab. There you will see the email templates for different actions (reset password, etc.)

At the top right of the template, you will see a "pencil" icon, click on it. You will be able to edit some fields and to configure a custom domain. Click on the link and a popup will take you to the process of configuring your domain.

It will ask for your domain and then it will show you the DNS records that you will need to add to your domain DNS configuration. If everything goes well, it may take up to 48 hours to verify your domain.

After it gets verified, you will be able to send the emails using your domain extension "@yyy.com".

Comment: Thank you. That seems to have worked, I am now just waiting for the verification process.